# Integer solutions of system of inequalities

Tags: inequalities, enumerative-combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

I am trying to solve a problem in combinatorics and I came up with the following system of inequalities:
$0\leq x<y<z\leq n$ and $x+y<n$ and I am trying to count the number of integer solutions. Obviously, the number of solutions of the first one is $\binom{n+1}3$ but I am not sure how to count the number of solutions which solve both equations simultaneously.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: https://oeis.org/A034828

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align}
\sum_{x=0}^{\lfloor (n-2)/2\rfloor} \sum_{y=x+1}^{n-1-x} \sum_{z=y+1}^n 1
&= \sum_{x=0}^{\lfloor (n-2)/2\rfloor} \sum_{y=x+1}^{n-1-x} (n-y) \\
&= \sum_{x=0}^{\lfloor (n-2)/2\rfloor} (n-1-2x) \frac{(n-(x+1))+(n-(n-1-x))}{2} \\
&= \frac{n}{2} \sum_{x=0}^{\lfloor (n-2)/2\rfloor} (n-1-2x) \\
&= \frac{n}{2} \left\lfloor \frac{n}{2} \right\rfloor \frac{(n-1-2(0))+(n-1-2\lfloor (n-2)/2\rfloor)}{2} \\
&= \frac{n}{2} \left\lfloor \frac{n}{2} \right\rfloor \left(n-\left\lfloor \frac{n}{2}\right\rfloor\right) \\
&= \frac{n}{2} \left\lfloor \frac{n}{2} \right\rfloor \left\lceil \frac{n}{2}\right\rceil \\
\end{align}

Comment: I think that in your calculations, when $2x+1>n$ you interpret $ \sum_{y=x+1}^{n-1-x} $ as $- \sum^{y=x+1}_{n-1-x}$, which is a negative number, but in the counting it should be 0.

Comment: @NickS Thanks, corrected.

Answer (score 0):

One has only to count the triples in excess (those with $x+y\ge n$), distinguishing into even and odd $n$. For even $n$, there are $2\binom{\frac{n+2}{2}}{3}$ triples in excess. For odd $n$, there are $2\binom{\frac{n+1}2}{3}-\binom{\frac{n+1}2}{2}$. Removing this number from $2
\binom{n+1}{3}$ (and hopefully simplifying the expression) one gets your number of solutions (note that the corresponding gf is rational, which could maybe derived directly by a gf approach). However your sequence is A034828,   https://oeis.org/A034828 (here I left the computation).

*Edit: details.*  Just consider the number of triples with $0\le x<y<z\le n$ and of the bad ones among them, for each fixed $x=0,1,\dots$ For $x=0$ you have $\binom{n}{2}$ triples, all good (because $x+y=y<n$). For $x=1$ you have $\binom{n-1}{2}$ triples, one bad, namely $(1,n-1,n)$. For $x=2$ you have $\binom{n-2}{2}$ triples, $3$ of which are bad. For $x=k<n/2$ you have $\binom{n-k}{2}$ triples,  and those  with $x+y\ge n$ are  $\binom{k+1}{2}$. So the number of your triples is $\sum_{2j\ge n+1} \binom{j}{2}-\sum_{2j\le n+1} \binom{j}{2}$,  that gives the above formula using $\sum_{j=0}^n \binom{j}{2}=\binom{n+1}{3}$
(which can be further simplified as in the OEIS link).

Comment: Thanks! Can you explain a bit more how you came up with your formula?